# ExtJS Accordion event on unrendered components

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an accordion of 5 panels. Each panel contain a set of checkboxes. I want to attach the change event to the checkboxes. But as the panels are collapsed the checkboxes dont get rendered and as a result I cannot attache the events. Any idea how do I do this.

Note : I am using ExtJS designer to make the accordion and the checkboxes.

Stuff done so far.

I added a class to the checkboxes and tried to access them using the query

```
 Ext.query('.winrej');
```

this however gives me list of checkboxes from the panel that is open.

Answer (score 0):

If the checkboxes are not rendered yet you will not catch any user interaction events, so it doesn't make sense to subscribe to them. Try to subscribe to events after certain panel of accordion layout has been rendered. Or am I missing something? What exactly are you trying to achieve?